# Persist JSON document as a String

Tags: java, json, jpa, spring-boot

I have a controller that receives a JSON `RequestBody` like the one below:

```json
{  
   "status":"pending",
   "status1":"pending",
   "status2":"pending",
   "status3":"pending",
   "specs":{  
      "width":1000,
      "height":1507,
      ........some other fields, any number of fields..
   },
}
```

I have an `Entity`

```java
@Entity
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    public String status;
    public String status1;
    public String status2;
    public String status3;
}
```

and my Controller class:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void insert(@RequestBody MyBean myBean) {
    return myService.save(myBean);
}
```

My problem is that I want to store the value of `specs` (which is a JSON document) as a String in a Lob field and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried editing your `Entity` class to store a `specs` object, and then persist ? The new Specs object can have the width and height parameters.

Comment: I forgot to specify that my specs value is dynamic, so I would have width and height or not and some other fields also.

Comment: is there a scope of possible values in spec? Can you just make an object 'spec' with all possible fields?

Comment: No I can't because I don't know all the possible fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare specs as `public Map<String,Integer> specs;`
and to convert Object to json use Jackson fasterxml api as below

```
MyBean bean=new MyBean();
    bean.setId(new Long(1));
    bean.setStatus("pending");
    bean.setStatus1("pending");
    bean.setStatus2("pending");
    bean.setStatus3("pending");

    Map<String, Integer> temp=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    temp.put("width",1000);
    temp.put("height",1507);
    bean.setSpecs(temp);

    //Object to json
    StringWriter sw=new StringWriter();
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(sw,bean);
    System.out.println(sw.toString());


     //json to object
    MyBean newBean=mapper.readValue(sw.toString(), MyBean.class);
    System.out.println(newBean.toString());
```

If you want serialize only specs before saving then use same mapper.writeValue() function to convert specs to json string
for more information refer [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)